# I need to delete everything that comes after the last integer

Tags: mysql, string

I strings that read like this:

```
ex 1: BOL01RUM
ex 2: BOL050FAG
```

I need to keep only BOL01, and BOL050. Trimming and left() do not work because in some lines I need five characters, and in some others I need six. Substring_Index does not work because I do not have a repeated separator that I can refer to with the Index.

Is there a way to ask SQL to delete everything after the last Number/integer? I intend to obtain only BOL01 or BOL050 from these strings.

Adding Notes from the answers below:

> MySQL Version is 5.6.10, and the character length of the string varies from nine to 12, so there is no way to use left or right trimming.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that 1 string or 2 separate strings?

Comment: You don't happen to be on mysql 8.0 yet, do you?

Comment: Those two examples are two separate strings, which I used to show that for some I need the first five characters, and for some I need the first six - At the end you can see that some go from 1 (integer) to R (char) and some go from 0 (integer) to F (char). I am looking for a way to use the type (integer, char) to break these strings into two, and keep only the left side.

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3.9

Comment: Workbench version isn't important, MySQL version # is. If it's version 8, there's a REGEX_REPLACE function. If version 5.6, you'll have to do it in application code.

Comment: Do the strings always have 3 characters after the piece of the string that you want?

Comment: MySQL has functions for searching a string for a particular substring, but nothing for finding a type of character like digits. And nothing for finding the last occurrence.

Comment: You could write a stored function to do it. It will have to loop over the characters from the end.

Comment: I have the 5.6 version, and the string has a variable length of characters after the string I want - I need to work down at the application level. I have not heard of a way to have SQL identify the difference between a digit and a character within a string, and I think that is the basic function for this query to work. Has anyone found a way to differentiate a character from a number within the same string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This answer is based on the assumption (based on the question and comments) that the strings all start with 3 characters and then have 2 or 3 digits, followed by a non-digit and then an unknown number of other non-digit characters.

You don't mention whether you want to SELECT these values or UPDATE the table. If you want to SELECT them, it is almost certainly simpler to post-process the values at the application level. However you can achieve what you want in MySQL using this query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec1b76/1)):

```
SELECT IF(SUBSTRING(str, 6, 1) RLIKE '[0-9]', LEFT(str, 6), LEFT(str, 5))
FROM strings;
```

This checks if the 6th character in the string is a digit and if so returns the leftmost 6 characters, otherwise it returns the leftmost 5 characters.

If you want to update the table with the new values this is a bit simpler, you just need to run two update queries ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec1b76/1)):

```
UPDATE strings2 
SET str=LEFT(str,5)
WHERE str RLIKE '^...[0-9]{2}[^0-9]';
UPDATE strings2 
SET str=LEFT(str,6)
WHERE str RLIKE '^...[0-9]{3}[^0-9]';
```

As @Barmar mentioned, you could also use a stored procedure e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tail(str VARCHAR(12)) RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT LENGTH(str);
  WHILE SUBSTRING(str, i, 1) RLIKE '[^0-9]' DO
    SET i = i - 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN SUBSTRING(str, 1, i);
END
```